# In nested if-else conditions, control of C program not going further

Tags: c, loops, if-statement

I have to find second largest number among given n numbers but without using array.  I decided to use loops but the problem is that control of program is not going to `else if` <s>loop</s> condition.  I made a constraint that if I enter `-1` then loop will terminate, but after entering `-1` the program terminated completely. I just want to know what is the problem with my loops or conditions, or am I doing it wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i, j, max1 = 0, max2 = 0;
    for (j = 0; j <= 10; j++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &i);
        if (i == -1)
        {
            break;
        }
        else if ((i) >= (max1))
        {
            max2 = max1;
            max1 = i;
        }
        else if ((i) < (max1))
        {
            if ((i) > (max2))
            {
                max2 = i;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code so it is better readable.

Comment: How did you know what your code is doing ? I mean you are not tracking any variable at all !

Comment: Your code should probably print out the value; it doesn't attempt to do so.  You don't really need the parentheses around `i` and `max1` in `else if ((i) < (max1))`; it is sufficient (and clearer) to write: `else if (i < max1)`.

Comment: Use `continue` in place of `break`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `else` part within the for loop is not necessary. You can reduce the number of if-statements if you look at the second `else if`. `i` is definetely smaller than `max1`, so you can just use the condition of the nested if-clause.
Print out `max2` and it works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i, j, max1 = 0, max2 = 0;
    for(j = 0; j <= 10; j++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&i);
        if(i == -1)
        {
            break;
        }
        else if(i >= max1)
        {
            max2 = max1;
            max1 = i;
        }
        else if(i > max2)
        {
            max2 = i;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", max2);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code looks like scary man , why do you use () so much, anyway your answer is : after you finds out maximum one you should just do

```
if( i > max2) max2 = i;
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach used in your program is wrong. For example if the sequence of numbers contains all negative numbers then max2 will contain 0 though there is no such a value in the sequence.

And the program has incorrect logic. There is a premature exit from the program.

The valid code could look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const int N = 10;

    int max1, max2;
    int value;
    int count;
    int i;

    count = 0;

    for ( i = 0; i < N && scanf( "%d", &value ) > 0 && value != -1; i++, count++ )
    {
        if ( count == 0 || max1 < value )
        {
            if ( count != 0 ) max2 = max1;
            max1 = value;
        }
        else if ( count == 1 || max2 < value )
        {
            max2 = value;
        }
    }

    if ( count >= 2 ) printf( "The second maximum is equal to %d\n", max2 );
    else printf( "You have to enter more than one number\n");

    return 0;
}
```

For example for sequence

```
5 -3 1 0 -6 9 -9 8 -5
```

the output will be

```
The second maximum is equal to 8
```